# Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, frameworks, comments

```
def broadcast_display_and_form(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.cleaned_data['post']
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.person = request.user
            obj.post = post
            obj.save()

            readers = User.objects.all()
            for x in readers:
                read_obj = BroadcastReader(person = x)
                read_obj.post = obj 
                read_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/broadcast')
    else :
        form = PostForm()
    posts = BroadcastReader.objects.filter(person = request.user)
    return render_to_response('broadcast/index.html', { 'form' : form , 'posts' : posts ,} )
```

## My template

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load comments %}

```
{% block content %}
<form action='.' method='POST'>

    {{ form.as_p }}
<p>
  <input type="submit" value ="send it" /></input>  
</p>    
</form>

{% get_comment_count for posts.post as comment_count %}
{% render_comment_list for posts.post %}

{% for x in posts %}

    <p>
       {{ x.post.person }} - {{ x.post.post }}
    </p>

{% endfor %}    


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you post the traceback for the error as well?

Comment: anything to help myself out of the situation

Comment: As `sunn0` wrote, you should really post your traceback also.  We have no idea where the error is occurring, so it's hard to even begin.  Also, what is the definition for PostForm and BroadcastReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `posts.post` supposed to be? `posts` is a `BroadcastReader` `QuerySet`, and probably doesn't have such an attribute? I'm guessing the comment rendering tags are causing your error? Try removing them, or using `posts.0` or similar to debug.

Which "post" do you actually want to display comments for? Your view logic is unclear.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you guys , i had just put the url for comment framework in my application's urls.py instead of project's.. Thanks for you help

Comment: But now i want to hide the name , email and url fields for authenticated users.. How do i go about doing that ??

Comment: It would be best to open a new question, since this is almost completely unrelated.